# Installed KVM, but Virtual Machine Manager says localhost(QEMU)

Tags: kvm-virtualization, ubuntu-12.04, libvirt, qemu

My understanding is that KVM uses the CPU virtualization properties and is much faster than QEMU, which is emulation.

I used the Virtual Machine Manager to create the virtual machine. I am nearly certain that I chose the default, which was KVM.

**Why does it say in the tree dropdown, localhost(QEMU) with my virtual machine icon underneath?**

Comment: QEMU is KVM - see this question - http://serverfault.com/a/391932/277521

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure this out. KVM/QEMU/libvirt work together. By typing

```
virsh dumpxml W2K8
```

At the top of the output it shows:

```
<domain type = 'kvm' id='2'>
```

Another useful command is `virt-host-validate`